# How to start pwa application using window.open() or hyperlink without opening in browser?

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps

I have created two pwa angular apps and installed it in my ubuntu machine. From one application, i have a button, on clicking it I am invoking below code .

```
window.open(environment.studyAppURL);
```

The problem is the second app(studyAppURL) is always opening in browser instead of opening as pwa. 
How do I make the second app to not use browser when on clicking the button?

Comment: A PWA always runs in the user's browser. If you are hosting your PWA from an HTTPS server AND it has passed all of the chrome dev tools Lighthouse tests, the user can "Install" the PWA. Then it will run looking like a standalone app.

Comment: (1) Are you using an HTTPS server? (2) Does your app pass all the lighthouse PWA tests on that HTTPS server?  If yes to both of these, what browser are you testing with?

Comment: Hi, I have installed the PWA in my local machine successfully. Lighthouse tests are not passed as Im still developing it.

Comment: Eventhough I have installed the PWA, when i click on the hyperlink with address of the app from other sites, the link is opening in chrome(this is the browser Im testing) instead of opening as PWA, The behaviour is for Desktop(OS: Ubuntu)

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. If you want to test the full functionality of a PWA you will first need to make sure it is valid code with the Lighthouse test, then host it on an HTTPS server.